# C++ ispunct deletes entire string?

Tags: c++

Hi im trying to use ispunct() on the following text file

```
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.
```

using the following code

```
int count = 0;
std::string fileName;
std::fstream readFile;
std::string storeFile;
char myWord[50000];

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

  std::cout << "Please enter the name of the file: " << std::endl; //prompts user for the filename
  std::cin >> argv[0]; //stores the filename is the first element of argv[
  fileName = argv[0];

  readFile.open(fileName);

  if (!readFile) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: failed to open file " << std::endl; //if the file cannot be opened an error is displayed
    exit(0); //if it cannot open the console terminates
  } else {
    std::cerr << "File successfully opened" << std::endl;
  }

  while (readFile >> storeFile) {
    if (readFile.bad()) {
      std::cerr << "File failed to read " << std::endl;
      break; //loop terminates
    } else {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(myWord) / sizeof(myWord[0]); i++) {
        if (ispunct(storeFile[i])) {
          storeFile.erase(i);
          readFile >> myWord[i];
          count++;
        }
      }
    }

    readFile.close();
    return 0;
  }
}
```

however when i run my program the function deletes the entire textfile, meaning nothing is retured. Im trying to simply delete the puncuation from the text file(IE ' , : and .) Thankyou

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your posted `storeFile` has no elements but 50000 "elements" of that are accessed. Is this your real code?

Comment: @MikeCAT I have changed this

Comment: Besides the out-of-range access problem, your code have no statements to output something other than prompts and error messages. This should be why "nothing is returned".

Comment: And it's clear that, for some reason, you expect every line read from that file to have at least 50000 characters in it. Is that true? If not, why are you attempting to access exactly 50000 characters in `storeFile`, attempting to erase from it, and then, for some reason, reading one character from the file. You should  definitely [try explaining this program to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). The reason you get no output is because the program is crashing. Badly.

Comment: because 50000 characters is the limit that was been set for this particular university level lab task @SamVarshavchik

Comment: @MikeCAT that is because i didnt include the for statement that returns the data

Comment: "50000 characters is the limit" is not logically equivalent to "every line must have at least 50000 characters", which is what the shown code assumes, and if it doesn't, it will crash miserably.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The program works as intended if puncuation didn't have to be removed. No crashes occur

Comment: Also note that `std::cin >> argv[0]; fileName = argv[0];` has a risk of buffer overrun and it should be simply `std::cin >> fileName;`.

Comment: The loop assumes that there are at least 50000 characters between whitespace in the file, and then it goes: Read one word from the file. Every time you encounter a punctuation character in that word, remove everything in the word from that point and read one character from the file. Repeat.

Comment: And if the file is completely empty, the program will also work, too. That doesn't mean anything.

Comment: 1. `i < sizeof(myWord)/sizeof(myWord[0])` should be `i < storeFile.size()` 2. `i--;` should be added after `count++;` to have it check the character after deleted character. 3. change invokation of `erase()` as @AlanBirtles says.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete all punctuation characters in the file try this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string filename;
    std::cin >> filename;

    std::ifstream file(filename);

    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening file: " << filename << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << file.rdbuf();

    std::string text = buffer.str();

    text.erase(
        std::remove_if(text.begin(), text.end(), [](auto c) {
            return std::ispunct(c);
            }),
        text.end()
        );

    std::ofstream out("out.txt");
    out << text;

    return 0;
}
```

With `file.rdbuf()` you read the complete file into the ifstream. No need for doing this line by line.
`std::remove_if` then swaps all punctuation to the end of the string where it get's `erase`d.

As you can see there is no need for reserving the buffer with 50000 characters.

Comment: Note that `return -1;` is not portable. There are three values that can be returned from `main` portably: `EXIT_SUCCESS`, `EXIT_FAILURE`, and `0`. Returning 0 is equivalent to returning `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string::erase(size_t)` calls the first overload of [`std::string::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) which has a second parameter `count` which is defaulted to `npos`. Therefore `storeFile::erase(i)` erases everything after the specified index.

To erase a single character explictly set `count` to `1`: `storeFile::erase(i, 1)`.

Comment: I think there are many other problems in your code, e.g. `i` goes from `0` to `50000` but `storeFile` doesn't have `50000` characters

Comment: shoulld i set the size of char myWords to the size of store file?

Comment: Depends what your code is supposed to do, its not clear what the code is supposed to do or what `myWord` is for